# How can I get the server time in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a plugin to tell what time it is in my SMP server (time in game) without changing the time? I'm hoping for a plugin, and not a mod like Single Player Commands that I have to compile into the server .jar. My other idea is to parse the logs for the last time someone used /time and figure it out from there.

Comment: What does `/time add 0` do? I can't check right now but that could be what you want.

Comment: It prints "10:48:29 [INFO] CONSOLE: Added 0 to time". I'd still have to dig back through the logs for the last time someone set it to an absolute time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. The data is in the level.dat file. Assuming you're using Python, here's a code snippet that should get the current time (run "sudo pip install nbt" first):

```
import nbt
def get_time():
    n = nbt.NBTFile('%s/%s/level.dat' % (minecraft_dir, session_name))
    if n == None:
        return None
    else:
        return n[0]["Time"].value % 24000
```

For bonus points, you can change the modulo to a division sign and get how many days it has been since you started.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is **Dynmap**.  We have it on our server to provide multiple features such as:

> The current version
>   of Dynmap provides an in-browser map, like Google Maps, of your
>   Minecraft world. It updates the map in realtime while you have your
>   browser opened and shows the current players, regions and in-game
>   messages on top of the map. It also allows viewers of the map to chat
>   from within their browser with players in-game.

This mod **does show in game realtime on the server**.
[See here for more more details, download URL, and installation instructions.](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/misc-dynmap-v0-37-real-time-minecraft-maps-1-1-r4-1-2-5-r1-0.489/)

[image]

[Source of screenshot](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/dynmap/images/1-screenshot/)

Comment: Seems a little much JUST to get the game time..

Answer (score 1):

There are probably simpler plugins which achieve the same thing, but with the bukkit plugin essentials, there is the command /time, which gives the time in the world. coupled with a script such as https://github.com/iman1000000/minecraft-cgi (this example only works if server is running command-line inside the linux program screen) it could be possible to output the time into a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Dynmap can do this as Foxtrot said.
However you can get something to show everything, such as Most kills/users online. Everything.

[Statistician v2](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/statisticianv2/) can do that for you.